# Can't detect audio jack card readers on Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0")

Tags: android, android-audiorecord, galaxy-tab

I'm trying to use an audio jack card reader (like a Square, but not a Square) on a Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0").  When it didn't work, I wrote a test app that does nothing except detect when something is plugged into the audio jack.  The app receives `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` intents as expected when you plug in headphones, but receives nothing when you plug in the card reader.  I tried a different reader from a different manufacturer, and it didn't work, either.  We tried several Tab 2s with the same results.  But the same test app receives `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` from the card swipes on other Android devices, including other Samsung devices.  The only combination that doesn't work is a card swipe with a Tab 2.

The plugs on the headphones and readers have the same number of conductors and look identical in every respect, and they were all fully inserted.

I've seen oddball devices require permissions they shouldn't, so I'm hoping someone knows of a permission or setting unique to the Tab 2 that might explain this problem.

My test app's only activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView statusText;

private final BroadcastReceiver headsetReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean plugged = (intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1);
        statusText.setText(plugged ? R.string.status_plugged : R.string.status_unplugged);
    }       
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(headsetReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
    super.onResume();
}

}
```

Comment: Although I'm not trying to use a Square Reader, it's interesting that Square specifically singles out the Verizon version of the Tab 2 as being incompatible with their product: https://squareup.com/help/en-us/article/3887-features-and-device-compatibility

Comment: Is a headset microphone combination fully functional for audio in both directions on that device?  I've seen at least one phone with a bad jack.

Comment: I verified that the hardware is fully functional by recording audio though a headset microphone at the same time audio was playing from a music player app.

I've now tested five different readers from four different manufacturers, and none of them work on the Verizon Tab2.  Two are not detected as anything being plugged in at all; the other three are detected as something being plugged in, but their SDKs can't talk to them.

Comment: An employee of the company whose library I'm trying to integrate into my own app did some legwork and found a couple other swipe manufacturers whose compatibility lists specifically exclude Verizon's Tab2.  So it looks like Verizon intentionally did something at the OS level to detect when a card reader is plugged in and prevent apps from using it.  I say intentionally because I can't imagine how they would *accidentally* cripple an entire category of audio jack devices, while ordinary headphones still work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/95459/p/30%2C6720%2C8882/kw/square

The pertinent part is:
Note: At this time, devices that have a microphone input but no microphone output (Square Card Reader, Jawbone UP) are not currently supported.

It's affecting Square readers on our tablets, so might impact you as well.